# How can i get SIM ID of both sim in dual android device...?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

By this code i'm getting only one SIM ID

```
TelephonyManager m = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String phoneNumber = m.getLine1Number();
String simId = m.getSimSerialNumber();
String phoneIMEI = m.getDeviceId();

tvSim.setText("Phone Number : "  + phoneNumber);
tvSimId.setText("SIM ID : " + simId);
tvImei.setText("IMEI" + phoneIMEI);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no general method to get info about second\third\fourth SIM in the device, even to detect their presence ;-(

All dual-SIM mechanisms are vendor-specific. This had been discussed a lot; please use search on stackoverflow.com to see details, and even to get some code sketches.